# MSAL/ADAL C++ equivalent to get access tokens

Tags: azure, oauth, adal, azure-ad-msal

Is there a MSAL/ADAL equivalent for C++ ? I would like to natively support getting access tokens for Azure in C++ (rather than build a bridge of some kind by using python version.)

Thank you

Comment: According to the documentation at [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries) (ADAL) and [Microsoft identity platform authentication libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-v2-libraries) (MSAL), there is no Microsoft supported library for C++ available.

Comment: Hence the question! Is there an "equivalent"

Comment: Also regarding the down vote. It is unfair. It leaves others wondering if there was indeed any research done. As a matter of fact I did scour through plenty if github repos and sites to check if there is an "equivalent" SDK that addresses the feature that MSAL/ADAL provide.I did not find any (not open source ones at-least). My question more precisely if there was any confusion is that "I know there is no port of MSAL/ADL in C++. However do any of you know if there are other libraries out there that do the job and are written in C++?"

Comment: I'm throwing my two cents for an upvote to this.  The question is, did anybody make a C++ library that allows for authentication against Azure active directory, and yes, I want one.

Answer (score 5):

I am the current contact at Microsoft for both MSAL or ADAL C++.

Microsoft has MSAL C++ in development and it will eventually be open source. Its code is used in major products made my Microsoft.
ADAL C++ is not released externally and is not open source.

Our guidance is to interop with Python or .NET at this time.

Comment: Would you happen to have an update on this? Is there an estimated timeline on when we can expect MSAL (C++) library?

Comment: What kind of bad joke is Microsoft's support for C++?

Comment: Well, the endpoints adhere to open standards, so there is no requirement to use a Microsoft library.  Microsoft just didn't prioritize ever releasing this due the lack of demand.

Comment: @Rags which solution did you used to get AD working with C++ ? I´m using VS C++ 2015

Comment: I ended up composing a library in C using Go FFI (CGo) for the MSAL Go package https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-go . I preferred Go (CGo) since I end up with a single .so/,dll and no other env setup which would be needed for (python/C#) MSAL packages.

Comment: @Rags How did you use it ? Any go sample would be really appreciated.
I used another go lib named adal and the AD token was bad

Comment: This is two  years old. Any news on that?

Comment: I'm no longer the current contact for this.  Looks like they didn't officially open source that library yet, so I presume my statement is still accurate.

Answer (score -1):

There actually is a C++ ADAL SDK, Microsoft releases it to partners and uses it internally.
It is not generally available, but if your company has a liaison with Microsoft, you can ask for it.

Comment: I'm the Lead Program Manager for ADAL/MSAL.  This statement is inaccurate.  The ADAL C++ library is limited in scope and in the final stages of retirement.  It is not made available to any Microsoft partners.  We have started work on an MSAL C++ library, but it will not be available until calendar year 2022.  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-active-directory-identity/update-your-applications-to-use-microsoft-authentication-library/ba-p/1257363

Comment: There's nothing in your statement that contradicts my statement or makes it inaccurate except the notion that Microsoft does not share it with partners. Well, I worked for a company that is MS's partner, and we got the ADAL C++ library from MS. 
So what is inaccurate in my statement? I never said it is not limited in scope (though we were able to do everything we needed with it), I never said anything about retirement (also, Microsoft's final stages of retirement can easily mean 10 more years, and I can give you examples).

Comment: @SaeedAkhter Do you have any updates regarding MSAL C++ library now? As it's almost end of 2022 I am hoping some tangible progress would have been made by now.